# Onsen-ui: How to force Android look and feel on ios device?

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

Using Onsen-ui v2, is it possible to keep the same look and feel on both Android and ios ? I would like my app to have the same UI look and feel on both platforms. Can I for example, have the Android look and feel on ios ? How ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `ons.disableAutoStyling()` right after including `onsenui.js`. This way, the auto styling will not add Material Design effects to the components. Otherwise, you can also set the desired platform with `ons.platform.select('ios')` or `ons.platform.select('android')`, but the first method is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is the reason it is not a good idea to simply set ons.platform.select('android') on ios ?

Comment: Because other things like `ons.platform.isAndroid()` will be affected. Therefore, if you need to detect the platform for some specific feature, you'd need to use something else (like Cordova device plugin). It is not a big issue, though.